# how to use CryptoJS in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I used [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) instead of `nodejs` crypto module because I just use the native JavaScript，but some codes can't work:

```
function aesEncrypt(text, secKey) {
  const _text = text
  const lv = new Buffer('0102030405060708', 'binary')
  const _secKey = new Buffer(secKey, 'binary')
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-128-CBC', _secKey, lv)
  let encrypted = cipher.update(_text, 'utf8', 'base64')
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64')
  return encrypted
}
```

So how should I modify these codes?

Answer (score 28):

Here's a sample on how to use CryptoJs in webclient:

```js
// INIT
var myString   = "blablabla Card game bla";
var myPassword = "myPassword";

// PROCESS
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(myString, myPassword);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, myPassword);
document.getElementById("demo0").innerHTML = myString;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = encrypted;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = decrypted;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
</head>


  
  <strong><label>Original String:</label></strong>
  <span id="demo0"></span>

  <br>
  <br>
  
  <strong><label>Encrypted:</label></strong>
  <span id="demo1"></span>

  <br>
  <br>
  
  <strong><label>Decrypted:</label></strong>
  <span id="demo2"></span>

  <br> 
  <br>

  <strong><label>String after Decryption:</label></strong>
  <span id="demo3"></span>

  
  <br />
  <br />
```

#### NB:

You might want to use CDN if you don't want to use node modules.

Comment: thank you very much, but how to use createCipheriv function ,  CryptoJS doesn't seems to  have that function.

Comment: I don't think there is function called createCipheriv in github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: Yes, I think so. So I want to modify those codes to implement the same function.

Comment: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/search?q=createCipheriv&unscoped_q=createCipheriv

Comment: What if the JS is in a different file from the html?  This example does not tie together the js with the html.  I get a  CryptoJS not found.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Everything is done using CryptoJs library. I merely used the html here to download the library for the online demo. If I were to use it in a NodeJs project I would install it directly using npm install crypto-js

Comment: I suggest you open a question explaining the details of your case

Comment: good answer, but you must use toString func to show encrypted string:
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = encrypted.toString();

Answer (score 10):

How about CryptoJS?

It's a solid crypto library, with a lot of functionality. It implements hashers, HMAC, PBKDF2 and ciphers. In this case ciphers is what you need. Check out the quick-start quide on the project's homepage.

```js
 var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
//U2FsdGVkX18ZUVvShFSES21qHsQEqZXMxQ9zgHy+bu0=

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
//4d657373616765


document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = encrypted;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = decrypted;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

```html
Full working sample actually is:

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<br><br>
<label>encrypted</label>
<div id="demo1"></div>
<br>

<label>decrypted</label>
<div id="demo2"></div>

<br>
<label>Actual Message</label>
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

Comment: How can the javascript be run from a different file than the html?

Answer (score 0):

Just for compelete previouse answers, you must use toString function to show the result as string because encrypt and decrypt functions returns object:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
console.log(encrypted.toString());
console.log(decrypted.toString());
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```