# Is there a way I can access crypto library in js?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a website that takes plain text and hashing it into `md5` hash, I don't know how websites implement those things, and how can I access this library ?

```
const md5 = require('crypto');
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome, I mean you want to store into a database the hashed or encrypted password a user store when by example is creating a username and password?

Comment: @HasanPatel Hi. No, I don't want to create a database. I want to know how to access the `crypto` library when not using `nodejs` or something else. Access it functions in my website.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005488/how-to-use-cryptojs-in-javascript/51005584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CryptoJS is a growing collection of standard and secure cryptographic algorithms implemented in JavaScript using best practices and patterns. They are fast, and they have a consistent and simple interface.

This is a way to call it without nodejs using the scripts, better to use the full cryptojs library.

```js
var plaintext   = "Hello World";
var encriptedtext = CryptoJS.MD5(plaintext)
document.getElementById("md5").innerHTML = encriptedtext
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>

<span id="md5">MD5: </span>
```

You need an Encoder to convert from encoding formats to WordArray objects and vica versa
Example:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Utf8
```

Now it is valid to point out MD5 is kind outdated and not recomended to store passwords and it is better to use SHA please review this link:
[MD5 vs SHA](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/md5-vs-sha-1-vs-sha-2-which-is-the-most-secure-encryption-hash-and-how-to-check-them/#:%7E:text=The%20SHA%2D256%20algorithm%20returns,MD5%20or%20SHA%2D1%20hashes.)

Comment: Thanks. But why would you use `var` instead of `let` ? I heard that `var` is an **oldschool** way and we should use `let` instead.

Comment: let works very much like var. The main difference is that the scope of a var variable is the entire enclosing function
[Using let and var what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)